# i want to upload a file from frontend to azure blob storage using restapi without using sdk using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-blob-storage

iam trying to upload any files to azure blob storage without using sdk using restapi in asp.net mvc

i got error if the content type image mean it will uploaded image only if i change content type file mean it will upload a file type but i need to upload every file to azure blob

here is my complete code.. please can anyone done this share the complete code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCuploadfile.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            byte[] imageBytes = null;
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
            imageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)file.ContentLength);

            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                //string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), _FileName);
                //file.SaveAs(_path);
            }

            string storageKey = "account-key";
            string storageAccount = "account-name";
            string containerName = "fileuploads";
            string blobName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            string method = "PUT";
            //int sampleContent = file.ContentLength;
            //byte[] fileBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(file.ContentLength)
            byte[] fileBytes = imageBytes;
            ///int contentLength = Encoding.GetBytes(fileBytes);
            // int contentLength = sampleContent;

            string requestUri = "https://gallerywebphp.blob.core.windows.net/fileuploads/" + blobName;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);

            string now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");

            request.Method = method;
            request.ContentType = "image/png";
            request.ContentLength = file.ContentLength;

            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2017-04-17");
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now);
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader2(method, now, request, storageAccount, storageKey, containerName, blobName));

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                //requestStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sampleContent), 0, contentLength);
               requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, file.ContentLength);
            }

            //using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode.ToString());
            //    Console.ReadKey();
            //}
            return View();


        }

        public static string AuthorizationHeader2(string method, string now, HttpWebRequest request, string storageAccount,
            string storageKey, string containerName, string blobName)
        {

            string headerResource = $"x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:" + now + "\nx-ms-version:2017-04-17";
            string urlResource = "/gallerywebphp/fileuploads/" + blobName;
            string stringToSign = method + "\n\n\n" + request.ContentLength +
                "\n\n" + request.ContentType + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + headerResource + "\n" + urlResource;


            HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(storageKey));
            string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));

            String AuthorizationHeader = String.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", "SharedKey", storageAccount, signature);
            return AuthorizationHeader;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HTTP has special characters so you either need to use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string)
 which replaces the characters with escape sequences or use convert to a 64 bit string.  See : https://www.classe.cornell.edu/~dms79/LectureNotes/formulae/List%20of%20XML%20and%20HTML%20character%20entity%20references%20-%20Wikipedia,%20the%20free%20encyclopedia.htm?force_isolation=true

Comment: I believe you have shared your real account name and key in the post. Even though I have edited the post and removed those but anybody can go through edit history and get those values. I would strongly recommend to change the account key immediately to prevent unauthorized use.

Comment: Not sure what exactly is the issue with your code. Please edit your question and describe the problem clearly.